Android Studio - Push Notifications not appearing in the 'Running Devices' emulator
I am currently working on a schedule reminder feature for my app which can send reminders to your phone at a selected time via push notifications. I've written out the code in the following Kotlin class labelled NotificationsWorker.kt:
package com.example.project.ui.screens

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters

class NotificationWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val title = inputData.getString("title") ?: return Result.failure()
        Log.d("NotificationWorker", "doWork called. Title: $title")
        showNotification(title)
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun showNotification(title: String) {
        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel =
                NotificationChannel("reminders", "Reminders", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "reminders")
            .setContentTitle("Reminder")
            .setContentText(title)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), notification)
    }
}


But for some reason, the push notifications aren't appearing in the emulator (The 'Running Devices'). The emulator that I'm using is 'Medium Phone API 35'.
I've written out the code:
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val title = inputData.getString("title") ?: return Result.failure()
        Log.d("NotificationWorker", "doWork called. Title: $title")
        showNotification(title)
        return Result.success()
    }

so it'll appear in the Logcat log viewer window, and when I sending a push notification in the emulator, I get the 'doWork called. Title: test' message in the log, which means it knows that a notification has been received, but it's not showing up in the emulator.
What can I do to make the emulator receive push notifications so I know that the reminder has been received?
